# How to filter visuals in one page based on a table value selected on another

Tags: powerbi

I saw a power bi dashboard that allows me to click on the ID number in a table then when I click on a button, it shows another page and everything is already filtered to that ID number. I don’t have the file (just saw the published dashboard) so I don’t know how they did it. Note that I don’t want a slicer. I want to be able to click on the ID in the table visual and automatically filter another page.

Comment: It's the drill through functionality

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, it’s the drill through function